# seagate U series 9: compatible with pi?

Tags: storage

My digi box I disassembled recently, and it yielded an 80 gb Seagate U series 9 hard drive. Put simply, can I use it with my pi?

Comment: Is this a USB drive?  SATA?  Please be more descriptive in thw question.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to buy a USB external HDD case for IDE (PATA) drives, or a USB to IDE cable.

Comment: ok. thanks. But in theory, the drive will be compatible?

Comment: yes. You just need to find a way to hook it up to the USB. I don't know what formatting the digi box used, so count on probably having to reformat the drive, but I see no reason it would not work. I have a 20GB iPod drive with a USB adapter i got on EBay ages ago connected to mine. You might find it is more cost effective, and certainly tidier to just buy a USB thumb drive or large SD card though. You need at least a small SD card to boot from anyway. The Pi has to boot from SD card, but should be able to use any HDD connected to the USB once it is up and running.

Comment: Yup. Rather thank buying larger storage, this is a pet project I'll be undertaking. Besides, the hard drive's only worth about £20, so it doesn't matter if I wreck it.

Comment: @DouglasHenderson That would be quite an achievement; wrecking an harddrive. Unless you plan on putting it and the Pi inside a bottle-rocket or something :-)